# AWS-CLI credentials not found using RStudio, but works fine from Windows CLI

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rstudio, aws-cli

When I issue an AWS-CLI command from the windows command line, `"aws s3 ls"` it successfully completes. When I try `shell(paste0("aws ", "s3 ", "ls"))` using R with Eclipse, it successfully completes.

However, on another machine using the same credentials, from the windows command line, `"aws s3 ls"` successfully completes, but with RStudio `shell(paste0("aws ", "s3 ", "ls"))` I get:

> "fatal error: Unable to locate credentials"

If I run `shell(paste0("aws ", "s3 ", "ls ", "--debug"))` from RStudio I get:

> 2017-02-27 15:07:10,516 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG -
>   Looking for credentials via: env 2017-02-27 15:07:10,516 - MainThread
>   - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role 2017-02-27 15:07:10,516 - MainThread -
>   botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via:
>   shared-credentials-file 2017-02-27 15:07:10,516 - MainThread -
>   botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via:
>   config-file 2017-02-27 15:07:10,516 - MainThread -
>   botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via:
>   ec2-credentials-file 2017-02-27 15:07:10,516 - MainThread -
>   botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via:
>   boto-config 2017-02-27 15:07:10,516 - MainThread -
>   botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via:
>   container-role 2017-02-27 15:07:10,516 - MainThread -
>   botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: iam-role
>   2017-02-27 15:07:10,520 - MainThread -
>   botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO -
>   Starting new HTTP connection (1): xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 2017-02-27
>   15:07:10,523 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - **Caught exception
>   while trying to retrieve credentials: ('Connection aborted.',
>   error(10051, 'A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable
>   network'))** Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "botocore\utils.pyc", line 159, in _get_request   File
>   "botocore\vendored\requests\api.pyc", line 69, in get   File
>   "botocore\vendored\requests\api.pyc", line 50, in request   File
>   "botocore\vendored\requests\sessions.pyc", line 465, in request   File
>   "botocore\vendored\requests\sessions.pyc", line 573, in send   File
>   "botocore\vendored\requests\adapters.pyc", line 415, in send

For the successful case from the Windows command line, it finds the credentials as seen below:

> 2017-02-27 15:07:03,267 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG -
>   Looking for credentials via: env 2017-02-27 15:07:03,267 - MainThread
>   - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role 2017-02-27 15:07:03,267 - MainThread -
>   botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via:
>   shared-credentials-file 2017-02-27 15:07:03,267 - MainThread -
>   botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in shared credentials
>   file: ~/.aws/credentials

So, what I am trying to figure out is why the AWS CLI cannot find the credentials using RStudio, but it works fine from the Windows CLI.

UPDATE: I have installed Eclipse on both machines and it works fine. However, it is still not working with RStudio, so it must be an IDE-related issue. Any ideas?

Comment: You might try instead using the [**aws.s3**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=aws.s3) package, which gives you a native R interface to S3.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I am no longer working on this project and cannot try it out. Seems like a good option though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by defining AWS credentials in RStudio:

```
Sys.setenv ("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "YourKEY_ID",
           "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "YOURSECRETACCESSKEY",
           "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "eu-west-1")
```